# Calling a stored procedure then interface fails

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I currently don't get the whole idea of stored procedures because why implement it on database when you can have the logic on your application (though I've already read references about this one so no need to thoroughly answer this)?

My real question is if a user sends a request then the request will run a stored procedure and if on user's end his/her application crashes (or unit unexpectedly shuts down), will the stored procedure finish the whole function, or it will also stop? Since the database server is still up and running..

I'm very sorry I'm really new to this.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: That will depend on the **actual RDBMS** you're using. SQL is just the query language - not a database product - please add a relevant tag to show what RDBMS you're using which this question concerns....

Comment: Sorry, i thought stored procedures on different RDBMSes works the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It depends. If request will run a stored procedure and packet has been sent to mysql server then it will be completed without no doubt.

Comment: Yes it will run a stored procedure and thanks a lot! It cleared my mind now.